# LWC DataTable with Account Records with checkbox and Submit Button

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, wrapper-class

I have an LWC component with 10 Account Records with a checkbox and submit button. My question is: Whenever I select multiple Account Records, modify Account field values, and click on the submit button, it should send the latest data to the apex and update the database & then it should display updated Account Record values in LWC Component.

When I select Multiple account records I can capture all the Account record details. Still, I am unsure how to capture modified Account field values when the checkbox is selected and after clicking on submit button how to send the latest data to apex to update in Salesforce?

I just started learning LWC. Looking for valuable suggestions/help on this. Thanks!

[image]

```
Js Code:

import { LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getAccList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountWrapperClass.getAccounts';
import updateSelectedContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountWrapperClass.updateSelectedContacts';

export default class WrapperTable extends LightningElement {
    selectedAccounts = [];
    accList;
    @wire(getAccList)
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
      if (error) {
        let message = "Unknown error";
        if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
          message = error.body.map((e) => e.message).join(", ");
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === "string") {
          message = error.body.message;
        }
      } else if (data) {
        this.accList = JSON.parse(data);
      }
    }
    handleAllChange(event) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.accList.length; i++) {
        this.accList[i].isSelected = event.target.checked;
      }
    }
    handleCheckChange(event) {
      this.accList[event.target.value].isSelected = event.target.checked;
    }
    getSelectedAccounts(event) {
     //enter image description here
     console.log(recordId, fieldName, fieldValue);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.accList.length; i++) {
        if (this.accList[i].isSelected) {
          this.selectedAccounts.push(this.accList[i]);
      }
    }
    
      console.log("###Selected Accounts" + this.selectedAccounts.length);
      console.log("###Stringify : " + JSON.stringify(this.selectedAccounts));
    }
  }
```

```
HTML :

<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_col-bordered" border="1" width="100%">
     
      <thead>
         <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
           <td>
             <lightning-input type="checkbox" onchange={handleAllChange}></lightning-input>
           </td>
           <td style="font-weight:bold">Account Name</td>
           <td style="font-weight:bold">Phone</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <template for:each={accList} for:item="acc">
        <tr key={acc.id} class="slds-hint-parent">
         <td>
            <lightning-input 
            type="checkbox" 
            checked={acc.isSelected}
            onchange={handleCheckChange} 
             value={acc.index}
             >
            </lightning-input>
         </td>
         <td>
    <lightning-input 
        type="text" 
        value={acc.AccountName}
    >
        ></lightning-input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <lightning-input 
    type="tel" 
    value={acc.Phone}
    onchange = {duplicate}
  ></lightning-input>
</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
 </table>
 <br/>
 <lightning-button label="Get Selected Accounts" onclick={getSelectedAccounts} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

```
public with sharing class AccountWrapperClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getAccounts(){
        Integer rowIndex = 0;
        List<accountWrap> accWrapList = new List<accountWrap>();
        try {
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account limit 10];
            for(Account a : accList){
            accWrapList.add(new accountWrap(a.Id,a.Name,a.Phone,rowIndex));
            rowIndex++;
            }
            return JSON.serialize(accWrapList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public class accountWrap{
        public String Id;
        public String AccountName;
        public String Phone;
        public Boolean isSelected;
        public Integer index;
        public accountWrap(String Id, String AccountName, String Phone, Integer index){
            this.Id = Id;
            this.AccountName = AccountName;
            this.Phone = Phone;
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.index = index;
        }
            
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

````js
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getAccList from '@salesforce/apex/accRecController.getAccounts';
import getUpdatedAccList from '@salesforce/apex/accRecController.udpateAccountRec';

export default class AccRec extends LightningElement {
    @track accList;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.getAccList();
}
    getAccList(){
        debugger;
        getAccList()
        .then((res) => {
            this.accList = res.accWrapList;
            console.log('Account List  ::>'+this.accList);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error in getting account list'+err);
        });
    }
    handleNameChanges(event){
        this.updateAccName = event.target.value;
    }
    handlePhoneChanges(event){
        this.updateAccPhone = event.target.value;
    }
    handleSubmit(){
        this.getUpdatedAccListJS();
    }
    getUpdatedAccListJS(){
        debugger;
        this.updateAccName = this.upAccName;
        this.updateAccPhone = this.upAccPhone;
        var data = { accountId : this.accId, accountName : this.updateAccName, accountPhone : this.updateAccPhone}
        var ajaxData = JSON.stringify(data);
        getUpdatedAccList({ajaxData: ajaxData})
        .then((res) => {
            this.accList = res.accWrapList;
            console.log('Account List  ::>'+this.accList);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error in getting account list'+err);
        });
    }
}``` 

```java
public with sharing class accRecController {
    public accRecController() { }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,list<Object>> getAccounts(){
        Integer rowIndex = 0;
        Map<String,list<Object>> response = new Map<String,list<Object>>();
        List<accountWrap> accWrapList = new List<accountWrap>();
        try {
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account limit 10];
            for(Account a : accList){
                accRecController.accountWrap aw = new accRecController.accountWrap();
                aw.Id = a.Id;
                aw.AccountName = a.Name;
                aw.AccountPhone = a.Phone;
                aw.AccountIndex = rowIndex;
                accWrapList.add(aw);
                rowIndex++;
            }
           response.put('accWrapList',accWrapList);
           return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,list<Object>> udpateAccountRec(String ajaxData){
        Map<String,Object> request = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(ajaxData);
        String accountId = (String)request.get('accountId');
        String accountName = (String)request.get('accountName');
        String accountPhone = (String)request.get('accountPhone');
        Integer rowIndex = 0;
        Map<String,list<Object>> response = new Map<String,list<Object>>();
        List<accountWrap> accWrapList = new List<accountWrap>();
        try {
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account where Id =:accountId];
            for(Account a : accList){
                accRecController.accountWrap aw = new accRecController.accountWrap();
                aw.Id = a.Id;
                aw.AccountName = accountName;
                aw.AccountPhone = accountPhone;
                aw.AccountIndex = rowIndex;
                accWrapList.add(aw);
                rowIndex++;
            }
           response.put('accWrapList',accWrapList);
           return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public class accountWrap{
        public String Id;
        public String AccountName;
        public String AccountPhone;
        public Boolean isSelected;
        public Integer AccountIndex;
        /* public accountWrap(String Id, String AccountName, String Phone, Integer index){
            this.Id = Id;
            this.AccountName = AccountName;
            this.Phone = Phone;
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.index = index;
        } */
    }
}```

> This will give you the gist of what you're trying to achieve.
````

Comment: Code dumps make for poor answers. How is this different from what OP already has (I'm assuming that there is a difference, I just can't be bothered to find it)? What problems does OP's original code have? How does this fix those issues? The explanation is as important as the solution.

Comment: Yes, you don't the difference I can see that. If you look to the bottom I said "This will give you the gist of what you're trying to achieve" That means OP knows his issue and I've written the method which will fix the 'Updated field values issue'.

Comment: That is not sufficient. Have you ever used this site (or another one like Stackoverflow) to get a solution to a problem you've faced? How many times was the actual solution to your problem _similar, but different_ from the answers? Keep in mind that your goal here is not only to help the person asking the question, it's to help _other people with similar issues_. Going into detail about the things I mentioned helps make answers useful for more than just a single person.